# Actual difference between organization owner and organization administrator in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am new to liferay and I am exploring User Roles.

I have created an organization and 2 users are associated with it say user1 and user2. User1 is organization owner and user2 is organization administrator.

Now my question is what is the actual difference between organization owner and organization administrator? What are the tasks that an owner can do and admin can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A Site/Organization Administrator cannot delete the membership of any other Administrator or Owner.

2) A Site/Organization Administrator cannot remove the Site/Organization Administrator or Owner role of other administrators/owners.

3) A Site/Organization Owner can delete the membership or remove the roles from any other administrator or owner.

From [this](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-31791) link

Comment: Okay. I understood this. Only this? I mean admin can do all other things that owner can, then why do we need different roles?

Comment: SIte/Organization admin can remove role or membership for an admin or Owner user from Site/Organization, this is why they have different roles.

Comment: Owners can also promote others to Administrators, while Administrators can't. However, you can have arbitrary powerful roles which Administrators can handle - just the SiteAdministrator role is special: It can't be granted by SiteAdministrators, just be SiteOwners.